# Are terms best introduced in abstract or introduction or repeated in both?

Tags: writing

I am writing a non experimental research paper in APA format. Should I define my terms in the abstract or in the intro or both?

Comment: Try to avoid defining terms in the abstract. But also, don't use undefined terms in the abstract. Better to explain in terms of commonly-used terms, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Define your terms in the body of the paper. Abstracts are meant to give a broad sense of the research question and conclusion, so that the reader knows whether or not they want to read the actual paper. Abstracts do not educate readers on new concepts.